# When a constant is referenced, is the value repeated in memory, or just the pointer like any other variable?

Tags: .net, constants

In .NET, if I define a constant (say a private constant in a class), will referencing that constant cause the value to be repeated in memory wherever it is referenced, or does .NET just use a pointer to where the constant is stored, the same as using any normal variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is incorporated in the IL (i.e. "repeated").  The alternative is to use the *readonly* keyword.

Do note that this is what makes a public *const* very dangerous.  A bug fix release may alter the value but any other assemblies that use the const still use the old value.  Only ever declare constants internal or private.  Use *readonly* for public declarations.  Unless it is a "manifest constant" that requires a change in the fabric of the universe.  Like Math.Pi

Comment: Thanks, sounds like consts are problematic, and at the very least a waste of bytes. Is there ever a reason to use a const over a readonly var?

Comment: Private constants are not a problem.  They do not waste bytes btw, referencing a readonly var takes more bytes and is slower.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of memory you mean: the constant will not be replicated in the *data* memory, but it will become part of the *code* memory embedded within the compiled IL code.

Comment: So if a class contains a const, then is that constant reallocated in memory for each instance of that class?

Comment: @Anthony Not for each instance, no: it is not in the data memory. The value will be replicated every time that you *use* the constant, inside or outside the class.